# system gets started after shutdown

Tags: shutdown, acer

I have Acer v5-571, which get started again after shutdown .After installing laptop mode tools the problem got solved but now also when I use a USB mouse then the problem comes till I do shutdown again.

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

this shutdowns the system i.e. halts the system.
for more please check  **man help** in terminal

Comment: I had tried many terminal option but they aren't working

Comment: How are they not working? Which behaviour do you observe and which do you expect? Is there any error message in the terminal output? Please [include](https://askubuntu.com/posts/532410/edit) your descriptions in your question.

Comment: I have no idea why the standard commands which  works elsewhere is not working in your device. Would you be more precise and accurate that we could understand the problem.